# TestNG How to skip all methods inside test if one method fails

Tags: ant, testng

I have a  in testng.xml which contains two classes, where each of them contains few methods to run. And if the first method in the first class fails, all other methods in this class are skipped, but the next class in this test is started. I need to skip everything in this test if one method fails:

```html
<test verbose="1" name="E2E" annotations="JDK">
  <classes>
    <class name="TestNG.personalCabinet">
      <methods>
        <include name="createCabinetAndLogin" />
        <include name="loginAndFillAgreement" />
        <include name="loginCreateShopAndCheck" />
      </methods>
    </class>
    <class name="TestNG.mobileBuy">
      <methods>
        <include name="mobileScan" />
        <include name="mobileBuy" />
      </methods>
    </class>
  </classes>
</test>
```

I launch it with ant:

```html
<target name="Test.E2E" depends="compile">
  <testng outputdir="${testdir}" classpathref="all.classpath" testnames="E2E" haltonfailure="true">
    <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
    <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" />
  </testng>
</target>
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I could define "mobileScan" dependent on "loginCreateShopAndCheck" but in my case it can be called as independent also!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comment,`dependsOnMethods` is what you look for.

> You can mark test method b() as depending on the successful run of test method a().  If a() failed, then b() will be marked as a SKIP, and not a FAIL.

http://beust.com/weblog/2004/08/19/dependent-test-methods/

Comment: That is a correct answer, but in my case, I call 2 different tests from testng.xml, one of them is just mobileScan and mobileBuy (as independant from personalCabinet class), and the other one is showd in question

Comment: Dependency between classes doesn't exists in TestNG but with effort you may add it by yourself. You may have all your test methods in a single classe too, and configure a different execution with groups ("personnalCabinet" and "mobileBuy")

Comment: Found one more solution: as I lauch all this with Ant, I declared dependencies in ant.xml: <target name="Test.E2E" depends="compile,TestLK.CreateShopAndCheck">